# Get compiled jade template inside view?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a "partial" template that I want to use both client-side and server-side.

Is there some method or filter or something that's very similar to `include` except that instead of executing the template immediately, it returns a client-compiled function which I could then assign to a JS variable and use throughout my script?

At present, I'm doing this:

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
    res.render('file/list', {
        ...
        fileItemTemplate: jade.compile(fs.readFileSync(path.join(req.app.get('views'),'file','file-item.jade')), {client: true})
    });
};
```

And then in my template I have:

```
ul#folder-list.thumbnails
    each file in files
        include file-item

...

script(type='text/javascript')
    var fileItemTemplate = !{fileItemTemplate};
```

And in this way I can render some items to HTML on page-load, and then add some more in later by rendering the partial as data comes in.

This works, but it doesn't feel very DRY because I have to read in the file, and deal with filepaths and stuff in the route, and then essentially redeclare the exact same variable client-side.

Is there a nice way of doing this?

Something like this would be ideal:

```
script(type='text/javascript')
    var fileItemTemplate = !{compile file-item};
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but you want your whole html template as a String? Isn't it easier to fetch the html template via an ajax request? That's easily done via express routes.

Comment: @asgoth: Not a string, a JavaScript function that can be re-used with different arguments. `jade.compile` returns a function. I could pass those arguments along with an ajax request and render the template server-side then pass back the HTML, but in this particular scenario I'm not actually using AJAX at all and I really don't want to add the overhead of hitting the server when it isn't necessary.

Comment: Could [JadeAsset](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11441944/1916258) help you out?

Comment: @asgoth: I didn't think about pre-compiling them all into a JS file; I guess I could do that. There might be a lot of junk in there that I'm not actually using client-side though. It looks like that's built for Asset-rack not Express, but I'll see if I can dig through the source and see how they did it. Thanks!

Comment: I've added it as an answer. Seems there is a hook for Express too.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be [JadeAsset](https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack#jadeasset). See also the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522542/how-to-compile-jade-templates-in-to-javascript-functions-to-use-them-on-client-s).

You can hook assets into Express:

```
assets.on('complete', function() {
    var app = express.createServer();
    app.configure(function() {
        app.use(assets);  // that's all you need to do
    });
    app.listen(8000);
});
```

To create your Jade assets:

```
var assets = new AssetRack([
    new rack.JadeAsset({
        url: '/templates.js',
        dirname: __dirname + '/templates'
    })
]);
```