# Prevent server side jade interpreting browser jade template

Tags: templates, browser, express, pug

I would like to pass jade template to the browser from a jade template in the server.

My problem is that the jade template are interpreted by the server at the moment...

Here is how I declare the template:

```
script#entry-row(type='text/template')
  tr
    td= number
    td= sum + '€'
    td= description || '' 
    td= moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SSSZ').format('dddd DD MMMM YYYY') 
    td 
      span.label= category
    td 
      input(type='checkbox', disabled='disabled', checked=shared)
```

The only solution I found was to add a pipe at the line begin but it's not a nice way:

```
script#entry-row(type='text/template')
  | tr
  |   td= number
  |   td= sum + '€'
  |   td= description || '' 
  |   td= moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SSSZ').format('dddd DD MMMM YYYY') 
  |   td 
  |     span.label= category
  |   td 
  |     input(type='checkbox', disabled='disabled', checked=shared)
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: I prefer the pipe syntax. Somewhat slower to type but quite easy to read and understand. By the way, thanks for sharing the solution. I spent almost half an hour on the search for any possible solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am recently haunting on this for several days, and i find a better solution.

You can rename your jade partial template to html extension, and include it in the main

jade page. So jade will not try to compile the included partials on serverside, and you

got what you want on browser side.

Here is my example coding:

***index.jade:***

```
extends layout

block content
  .container
    .header
      a= title
      .input-append
        input.input-medium(type="text", placeholder="电子邮箱")
        button.btn(id='subscribe') 订阅
      .clear
    .row-fluid 
      .span8
        ul.tweets
      .span3

        ul.users


  script#tweet-template(type='template')
    include templates/tweet.html
```

and the partial ***templates/tweet.html***

```
li
  .media
    img.pull-left(src=tweet.user_img)
    .media-body
      h5.media-heading= tweet.user_name
      p.text 
        span #{tweet.text}
        - if (tweet.pic_name != '') {
          br
          img.img-polaroid(src='/images/tweets/' + tweet.pic_name + '_thumb.jpg', class='thumb_img')
          img.img-polaroid(src='/images/tweets/' + tweet.pic_name + '_middle.jpg', class='middle_img')
        - }
      p.tail 
        - if (tweet.pic_name != '') {
          a(href='/images/tweets/' + tweet.pic_name + '_large.jpg') 查看大图
        - }
        span.time #{tweet.create_at} 
        转发(#{tweet.reposts_count}) 评论(#{tweet.comments_count})
```

Comment: I don't have time to try to but if it's work it's very nice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are using [express](http://expressjs.com/)?

A possible solution could be [JadeAsset](https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack#jadeasset). See also the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522542/how-to-compile-jade-templates-in-to-javascript-functions-to-use-them-on-client-s).

You can hook assets into Express:

```
assets.on('complete', function() {
    var app = express.createServer();
    app.configure(function() {
        app.use(assets);  // that's all you need to do
    });
    app.listen(8000);
});
```

To create your Jade assets:

```
var assets = new AssetRack([
    new rack.JadeAsset({
        url: '/templates.js',
        dirname: __dirname + '/templates'
    })
]);
```